# Telnet and traceroute In Iphone

Tags: iphone, sockets, telnet, traceroute

I am a beginner in programming for iphone.I want to develop traceroute and telnet app for iphone.Can you please provide me with some sample codes or pointers to start with.

Thanks,
Vinod.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with either set of protocols? If not I'd highly recommend you familiarize yourself with them in a more forgiving and powerful development environment and then port to the iphone.

Comment: ok ... i tried using apple open source traceroute it s working in MAC but no luck in iphone

Comment: Okay, there's no way I could have known this so that's why I asked. If you're going to downvote me for not being psychic I'll make sure to avoid any of your questions in the future.